# Relevant Question on Math Educators Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a question on the [Mathematics Educators Stack Exchange](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/) that might be of interest to the users here:

[How is calculus helpful for biology majors?](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/how-is-calculus-helpful-for-biology-majors)

We already have an answer from one biologist, but more answers from those familiar with undergraduate biology education would certainly be welcome.